# Is there an implicit cast to for_each's functor?

Tags: c++

So the 3rd argument of for_each is a functor, but I can give it a function name, is there an implicit cast and some temporary functor got created?

For example:

```
void Print(int n)
{
  cout << n;
}

void f(vector<int> &v)
{
   for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), Print);
}
```

I am wondering c++ compiler internally generates a functor from function Print?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each   function name is a function pointer.

Comment: If by "functor" you specifically mean a class type with a suitable overload of `operator()`, then no: `for_each` accepts any callable type, including function pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The prototype for `std::for_each` is

```
template<class InputIterator, class Function>
Function for_each(InputIterator first, InputIterator last, Function f);
```

(C++11 standard, 25.2.4 [alg.foreach])

So if you pass some sort of object with overloaded `operator()`, as the third argument, then `f` becomes a copy of that object; and if you pass `Print`, then `f` becomes a pointer to the function `Print` (since passing parameters performs function to function pointer conversion). But function pointers aren't "converted" to another functor type at the time when parameters are passed.

The implementation of `for_each` *may* choose to wrap `f` in some internal functor type. The standard doesn't specify how the function works. I can't see why it would do that though. Indeed, the implementation from my g++-4.7 headers is basically

```
for (; first != last; ++first)
    f(*first);
return move(f);
```

There was no need to store `f` in a functor object; all it does is call it directly. At compile time, the compiler will figure out what type `f` is, and hence what `f(*first)` is supposed to mean.

Note that the declaration doesn't prevent you from passing, say, the int `1` as the parameter `f`, but the line `f(*first);` will not make sense and *then* you'll get a compilation error. This is the sort of problem that *concepts* are supposed to address.

Comment: What throws me off is, "class Function" makes me think "f" must be a class while function pointer is not a class. So when a function pointer is passed in, is "Function" a pointer pointing to a function or a function?

Comment: `class Function` does not mean `Function` is a class; it just means it's a type. For this reason some people prefer to use `typename` instead of `class`.

Comment: Functions decay into function pointers when they are passed as parameters to other functions.

Answer (score 0):

The function parameter to for_each can be either a function pointer or a function object.  The function must accept an element from the range as a parameter.

In your case, Print is simply a function pointer.